# An error occured installing the plugin [shiro-1.1.3]: Unable to delete

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, shiro

Grails 2.0.0.M1 + shiro-1.1.3

> grails> install-plugin shiro
>
> | Resolving plugin JAR dependencies..
>
> delete logs...
>
> | Plugin installed.
>
> grails> compile --staktrace
>
> | Error An error occured installing the plugin [shiro-1.1.3]: Unable
>   to delete file
>   D:\TZProfile.grails\2.0.0.M1\projects\Vote\plugins\shiro-1.1.3\lib\shiro-co
>   re-1.1.0.jar
>
> | Error Error running script compile --staktrace:
>   org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli .ScriptExitException (Use --stacktrace
>   to see the full trace)

Answer (score 0):

You only need to delete all files .jar of D:\TZProfile.grails\2.0.0.M1\projects\Vote\plugins\shiro-1.1.3\lib. That is, uninstall the plugin. After that, install it again. Then, run the app.